# Netbeans 8.2 Stuck at loading screen Message Log

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, netbeans-8

I was able to open netbeans 8.2 successfully and no there was no error but just this morning I was shocked that I can't open it, it just stuck at loading screen specifically at "Loading module services". I think I somehow deleted some files that wasn't supposed to be deleted from netbeans 8.2 folders/files and now I can't open it. I may have deleted the netbeans cache folder and deleted some modules that was strictly required. I wasn't able to find any solution from any site. PS. I am on macOS Mojave.

Message Log:

```
>Log Session: Tuesday, January 19, 2021 9:30:41 PM PST
>System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) (#5fd841261bf9)
  Operating System        = Mac OS X version 10.14.6 running on x86_64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_271; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.271-b09; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_271-b09
  Java Home               = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_PH (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /Users/lewontabs
  Current Directory       = /
  User Directory          = /Users/lewontabs/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2
  Cache Directory         = /Users/lewontabs/Library/Caches/Netbeans/8.2
  Installation            = /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/java
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/apisupport
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/websvccommon
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/profiler
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/harness
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/javafx
                            /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform
  Boot & Ext. Classpath   = /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/System/Library/Java/Extensions/MRJToolkit.jar
  Application Classpath   = /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/boot.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-modules.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-lookup.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util-ui.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/org-openide-util.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/boot_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/boot_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/boot_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/boot_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-modules_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-lookup_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util-ui_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/lib/locale/org-openide-util_zh_CN.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_271.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
  Startup Classpath       = /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/org-netbeans-libs-asm.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems-compat8.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/asm-all-5.0.1.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/org-openide-filesystems.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/core.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/core-base.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core-base_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core-base_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core-base_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems-compat8_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-openide-filesystems_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/core-base_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/platform/core/locale/org-netbeans-libs-asm_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/org-netbeans-upgrader.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ja.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/org-netbeans-upgrader_zh_CN.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb_pt_BR.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ru.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/nb/core/locale/core_nb_ja.jar


INFO [org.netbeans.modules.netbinox]: Install area set to file:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/
Warning - could not install some modules:
    org.apache.commons.logging - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-logging.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.logging
    org.eclipse.equinox.common - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-common.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.common
    com.jcraft.jzlib - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/com-jcraft-jzlib.jar: Not found bundle:com.jcraft.jzlib
    org.apache.commons.io - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-io.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.io
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-runtime-compatibility-auth.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth
    org.apache.commons.codec - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-codec.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.codec
    org.eclipse.core.jobs - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-jobs.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.jobs
    org.eclipse.equinox.registry - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-registry.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.registry
    org.eclipse.equinox.app - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-app.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.app
    org.apache.commons.httpclient - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-httpclient.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.httpclient
    org.apache.commons.lang - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-lang.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.lang
    com.googlecode.javaewah.JavaEWAH - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/com-googlecode-javaewah-JavaEWAH.jar: Not found bundle:com.googlecode.javaewah.JavaEWAH
    org.eclipse.equinox.preferences - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-preferences.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences
    com.jcraft.jsch - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/com-jcraft-jsch.jar: Not found bundle:com.jcraft.jsch
    org.eclipse.jgit - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-jgit.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.jgit
    org.eclipse.core.contenttype - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-contenttype.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.contenttype
    org.eclipse.core.runtime - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-runtime.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.runtime
    org.eclipse.equinox.security - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-security.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.security
    org.eclipse.core.net - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-net.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.net
    com.google.guava - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/com-google-guava.jar: Not found bundle:com.google.guava
    org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-wikitext-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core
    org.apache.ws.commons.util - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-ws-commons-util.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.ws.commons.util
    org.apache.xmlrpc - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-xmlrpc.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.xmlrpc
    org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core
    org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-net.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net
    org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-xmlrpc.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc
    org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-repositories-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core
    org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-tasks-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core
    org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-bugzilla-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core
```

Comment: Try deleting the entire User Directory (`/Users/lewontabs/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.2`). But if you deleted files from the _installation_ directory, there is not much you can do apart from re-installing it. While you are at it, you could also upgrade to 12.2

Comment: Really on Netbeans 8.2 ?... Current version is 12.2 ...